# modify json object and save it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I do have a json array object. I need to modify it then save the modified version on a variable.

the json object

```
var json = [ 
{ 
  "Name": "March-2016", 
  "Elements": [ 
    { 
      "Name": "aa", 
      "Elements": [ 
        { 
         "Name": "ss", 
          "Data": { 
            "Test1": [ 
              22
            ], 
            "Test2": [ 
              33 
            ],
            "Test3": [ 
              44
            ],
            "Test4": [ 
              55
            ]
          } 
        },
        { 
          "Name": "ssee", 
           "Data": { 
             "Test12": [ 
               222
             ], 
             "Test22": [ 
               3322 
             ],
             "Test32": [ 
               445
             ],
             "Test42": [ 
               553
             ]
           } 
         }  
      ] 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

];

need to be modified to

```
 var json = [ 
{ 
  "Name": "March-2016", 
  "Elements": [ 
    { 
      "Name": "aa", 
      "Elements": [ 
        { 
         "category": "ss", 
            "Test1": 22, 
            "Test2": 33 ,
            "Test3":44,
            "Test4": 55 
        },
        { 
          "category": "ssee", 
          "Test12": 222, 
          "Test22": 3322 ,
          "Test32":445,
          "Test42": 553 
         }  
      ] 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

];

I have this method but its not doing the job

```
var saveJson = function(arr) {
var nameValuePairs = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  var item = arr[i];
  if (item.Data) {
    var newvar = {
       category : item.Name
     }
     newvar[Object.keys(item.Data)] = Object.values(item.Data);
     item = newvar

  }

  if (item.Elements) {
    nameValuePairs = nameValuePairs.concat(saveJson(item.Elements));
  }
}
return arr;
};
```

I need this conversion to be dynamic as for sure I will get bigger json than the posted one

sorry for the confusion and thanks in advance.

Comment: Valid JSON would be a good place to start.

Comment: Run your json thru this before posting: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: JSON is a serialization format. There is no JSON in this question.

Comment: Your new code totally changes the question. Why does `"Name": "ssee", ` turn into `"category": "ss333"`

Comment: its was in hurry modification. I did fix it

Comment: No it is still not JSON ;) See http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: You have a **JavaScript** array of **JavaScript** objects. You're misusing the name "JSON", there is no JSON anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original object is really a mess, but still you just need to step through it and pull out the values you want. This changes the `json` object in place:

```
json.forEach(item => {
  item.Elements.forEach(Outer_El => {
      Outer_El.Elements = Outer_El.Elements.map(item =>{
          let obj =  {category: item.Name}
          Object.keys(item.Data).forEach(key => {
              obj[key] = item.Data[key][0]
          })
          return obj
      })
   })
})
```

`json` should now look like:

```
[{
    "Name":"March-2016",
    "Elements":[
        {
            "Name":"aa",
            "Elements":[
                {
                    "category":"ss",
                    "Test1":22,
                    "Test2":33,
                    "Test3":44,
                    "Test4":55
                },
                {
                    "category":"ssee",
                    "Test1e":224,
                    "Test2e":334,
                    "Test3e":443,
                    "Test4e":554
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment to get specific property values from an object

```
{
  let {Name:categories, Data:{Test:[Test]}} = json[0].Elements[0].Elements[0];
  json[0].Elements[0].Elements[0] = {categories, Test};
}
```

Comment: Can we assume both the `Elements` arrays will only have one value?

Comment: @Mark_M Do not assume anything here. That is the code that we have at OP _"the json object"_

Comment: That's my point - your answer assumes these two array only have one element.

Comment: @Mark_M There is no assumption. There is only one element within array at code at original Question. The array used at Answer is the array at Question. Are you suggesting that additional requirements should be inserted into Question which do not appear at the text of the original Question itself? The same pattern can be used for any number of array elements having the same data structure.